# how many post author do want to show it author box

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want how many post do my site any author it show below in all post author box. how i can dot it. my author box css code show in below. [my site](http://dewdropzone.com).

```
/***** Author Box *****/
.post-gravatar { position: relative; width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 0 10px 0 0; float: left; }
.post-gravatar img { display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; background: #fcfcfc; padding: 4px; }
#author-box, #archived-author-box { position: relative; width: 598px; margin: 0 15px 25px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px; }
#author-box h3 { color: #222; font-size: 1.1em; margin: 0 0 10px; text-transform: uppercase; }
#author-text, #archived-author-text { position: relative; width: 528px; float: right; }
#author-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; margin: 0 0 10px; }
#archived-author-text p { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.6em; }
#author-text p a, #author-text p a:visited,
#archived-author-text p a, #archived-author-text p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
#author-text p a:hover, #author-text p a:active,
#archived-author-text p a:hover, #archived-author-text p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display the number of posts each author has written?

There's a function for that called `the_author_posts()` [(Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts)

For example, inside your loop you can use it like this:

```
<p><?php the_author(); ?> has blogged <?php the_author_posts(); ?> posts.</p>
```

which could translate something like

```
<p>Firstname Lastname has blogged 213 posts</p>"
```

Comment: where i get loop? and where?